# Creating Animation Map

Tags: r, ggplot2, animated-gif, gganimate, geostatistics

My issue is, I was supposed to create some animation map in R. I have very basic knowhow about R, but I love coding with it though. However, whenever I try to run my code it just gives me the below message.

```
Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "id", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, :
replacement has 2886 rows, data has 2826
```

I tried many things to fix it, but couldn't be successful anymore, so please I need help from anyone herein to support.

I have attached snapshot of my dataset as I couldn't upload the CSV format.

[image]

**Below is my R code:

```
# libraries we need
libs <- c(
  "tidyverse", "sf","ggmap",
  "gganimate", "classInt", "ggplot2"
)

# install missing libraries
installed_libs <- libs %in% rownames(installed.packages())
if (any(installed_libs == FALSE)) {
  install.packages(libs[!installed_libs])
}

# load libraries
invisible(lapply(libs, library, character.only = TRUE))
```

```
# 1. IMPORT DATA
#-----------
install.packages("readxl")
library("readxl")
setwd("D:\\R Tutorial\\Animate in R\\animate-maps-with-r-main\\animate-maps-with-r-main\\R\\Test")
number_benef_df <- read_excel("Number_of_Benificiary2.xlsx")
View(number_benef_df)
number_benef_df_vector <- as.vector(number_benef_df)
fix(number_benef_df_vector)

# 2. ETH SHAPEFILE
#-------------------
ETH_Woreda <- st_read("draft_ETH_Admins_2024\\ETH_Woredas.shp")
View(ETH_Woreda)
names(ETH_Woreda)
plot(sf::st_geometry(ETH_Woreda))
```

```
**# 3. JOIN DATA & SHAPEFILE
**#-------------------------
number_benef_sf <- dplyr::inner_join(
  ETH_Woreda, number_benef_df,
  by = c("admin3Pcod" = "Woreda_Pcode")
)
View(number_benef_sf)
```

```
**# 4. BREAKS
**#----------
vmin <- min(number_benef_sf$NO_Beneficiary, na.rm = T)
vmax <- max(number_benef_sf$NO_Beneficiary, na.rm = T)
brk <- round(classIntervals(
  number_benef_sf$NO_Beneficiary,
  n = 6,
  style = "fisher"
)
$brks, 1) |>
  head(-1) |>
  tail(-1) |>
  append(vmax)
breaks <- c(vmin, brk)

cols <- rev(c(
  "#001f3a", "#30314e", "#5c435f",
  "#8d5369", "#c0636c", "#dc8177",
  "#e6a988"
))
```

```
# 5. ANIMATE
#-----------
get_animated_number_benef_map <- function() {
  benef_map <- ggplot(
    data = number_benef_sf,
    aes(fill = NO_Beneficiary)
  ) +
    geom_sf(data = ETH_Woreda, fill = NA, size = 0.05, color = "grey70")+
    geom_sf(color = "grey70", size = 0.05) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(
      name = "",
      colours = cols,
      breaks = breaks,
      labels = round(breaks, 1),
      limits = c(vmin, vmax),
      na.value = "grey70"
    ) +
    coord_sf() +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(
      direction = "horizontal",
      keyheight = unit(1.5, units = "mm"),
      keywidth = unit(15, units = "mm"),
      title.position = "top",
      title.hjust = .5,
      label.hjust = .5,
      nrow = 1,
      byrow = T,
      reverse = F,
      label.position = "bottom"
    )) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      axis.line = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x = element_blank(),
      axis.text.y = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y = element_blank(),
      legend.position = c(.5, -.015),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 11, color = "grey10"),
      panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "white", size = .2),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      plot.title = element_text(
        face = "bold", size = 20,
        color = "grey10", hjust = .5, vjust = -3
      ),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(
        size = 40, color = "#c43c4e",
        hjust = .5, vjust = -1
      ),
      plot.caption = element_text(
        size = 10, color = "grey10",
        hjust = .5, vjust = -10
      ),
      plot.margin = unit(c(t = -.1, r = -2, b = -.1, l = -2), "lines"),
      plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA),
      legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA),
      panel.border = element_blank()
    ) +
    labs(
      x = "",
      y = "",
      title = "Benefiary Map",
      #subtitle = "Year: {as.integer(closest_state)}",
      caption = "©2023 Milos Popovic (https://milospopovic.net)
        World Development Indicators, The World Bank"
    )
  
  return(benef_map)
}

benef_map <- get_animated_number_benef_map()
print(benef_map)

timelapse_benef_map <- benef_map +
  gganimate::transition_time(
    time = as.Date(Start_Year)
  ) +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade() +
  ease_aes("quadratic-in-out", interval = .2)

animated_benef_map <- gganimate::animate(
  timelapse_benef_map,
  nframes = 120,
  duration = 20,
  start_pause = 3,
  end_pause = 30,
  height = 6,
  width = 7.15,
  res = 300,
  units = "in",
  fps = 15,
  renderer = gifski_renderer(loop = T)
)

gganimate::anim_save(
  "beneficiary_map.gif", animated_benef_map
)

gganimate::anim_save(
  "beneficiary_map.gif", animated_benef_map
)
```